# Bing Speech to Text API returning very wrong text

Tags: speech-to-text, azure-cognitive-services

I am trying the "Bing Speech To Text API" in audio files that contains a real conversations between a person that answer customers in a call-center, and a customer that calls the call center to solve his doubts. Thus, these audios have two persons talking, and sometimes have long silence period when the customer is waiting an answer from support. These audios have 5 to 10 minutes long.

My doubt is:

What is the best aproach to translate audios like that to text, using Microsoft Cognitive Services?

What APIs do I have to use, besides Bing Speech To Text?

Do I have to cut or convert the audios before sending them to Bing Speech To Text?

I am asking that because the Bing Speech to text API is returning an text very very very very very different from the audio content. It is impossible to use or undertand. But, of course, I think I am doing some mistake.

Please, could you explain to me the best strategy to work with audio files like this?

I would be very glad for any help.
Best Regads,

Comment: could you share your code?

Comment: Most likely input data format is wrong, like you are sending compressed audio while you need to send uncompressed pcm. For such task it is better to try specialized APIs like Kaldi.

Answer (score 0):

I had run into this problem with conversations as well. Make sure that the transcription mode is set to "conversation" instead of "interactive."